# Change formating of `\im' command in c.vim

Tags: plugin-c.vim, formatting

I have recently installed the c.vim plugin. The only issue is when I type `\im` (automatically adds the main function) this is the way how it displays it.

```
        int
main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}                               /* ----------  end of function main  ---------- */
```

As you can see it looks a bit messy (I think so at least!). Because of this is there a way how I can format it like this?

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To me this is much neater which is why I want to change it.

Comment: You'll have to patch the templates coming from c-support or use another plugin which will propose other snippets.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried looking at the templates but I cannot find the one I like. Do you know where it is?

Comment: IIRC, the documentation explains how to override a template. Search for "local template". NB: You can also hack in to the templates packaged but it won't be a good idea.

Comment: I have looked at the local template in search however I am not sure what to do. Could you give me the instructions please?

Comment: Sorry. I can't do more. So far, I've just grasped hints of a solution from the documentation -- and the way template expander could be implemented. As I said  in another Q/A, I'm not using c-support as I'm maintaining a concurrent C++ suite -- which would expand `main<c-space>` into something closer to what you are looking for, and if not, this time I'll know how to override `cpp/main` snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit `c-support/codesnippets/main.c` for C code and `c-support/codesnippets/main.cc` for C++

Otherwise it looks like the local version is stored in `~/.vim/bundle/cvim/c-support/templates`

There is a file called `c.idioms.template` that contains the `main` function.

Edit:

I'm using pathogen so my path looks a little different. Per the c.vim documentation

> The master template file is '$HOME/.vim/c-support/templates/Templates' for
>   a user installation and  '$VIM/vimfiles/c-support/templates/Templates' for
>   a system-wide installation (see csupport-system-wide).

More info at `:help csupport-templates-files`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will look into this soon. Where is $VIM (on a Mac)? I know $HOME is ~/ but not where $VIM/ .

Comment: Not sure on the Mac, Linux is /usr/share/vim typically. Probably pretty similar location.

Comment: I edited `c-support/codesnippets/main.cc` but it didn't work so I edited the `c.idioms.template` file and it worked. Thanks.